# gccgo linking Error in Ubuntu 9.10 karmic?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, go

I am trying to compile go file using gccgo , i installed on my ubuntu 9.10 machine . when i compiled

```
 $gccgo -c hello.go
```

hello.o file is generated , while trying to link and to form an executable

$gccgo -o hello hello.o

i get the following error

```
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../libgo.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../libgo.so: undefined reference to `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am i missing something ? , i have also set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH   in my environment . Thanks

Comment: Why use gccgo instead of the default compiler? gccgo is not as complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try following the advice in  [this post](http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2007-02/msg00009.html)  and pass `-march=i486` to the compiler? (or `-march=i686`)

Comment: @Supressingfire Thanks it did help to some extent , i have shared my experience in installing gccgo on ubuntu on my blog  http://gotiny.co.cc/google-gccgo .Hope this helps for the needy